# regex first occurrence before word

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have the following string:

```
:</w:t></w:r>xxxxxxxuyyyyyzzzzz:</w:t></w:r>xxxxuuuxxxyyyyyzzzzzsomemoney
```

My goal is to remove tags of string, finding the first ':' before the word `somemoney` like this

```
:</w:t></w:r>xxxxuuuxxxyyyyyzzzzzsomemoney
```

but I only get this

```
:r>xxxxuuuxxxyyyyyzzzzzsomemoney
```

I am using the following expression

```
~:(?:.(?!:))+somemoney~
```

Can someone help me, link for test: https://regex101.com/r/ibfY8s/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tags are as simple as in your example, you could do it with

```
:(?:<[^>]*>|[^:])*somemoney
```

This matches a colon followed by one of two alternations, up to the *magic word*. The alternations being

1. a starting `<` followed by any character (but `>`) up to the closing `>`, finally followed by the closing `>`.
2. any character but a colon (`:`).

The alternation can repeat any number of times.

The first alternation will "eat" the tags content, so it isn't tested against `[^:]`.

[Your modified regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/ibfY8s/3).

**Note!** If your tags can have arguments that can contain strings (like an HTML-tag), this gets **very** much more complicated.